# LocationManager requestLocationUpdates minTime OR minDistance

Tags: java, android, gps, android-4.4-kitkat, android-gps

I'm using Android's `LocationManager` and its method `requestLocationUpdates` like this:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 3000, 10, this);
```

As I found out both the conditions of minTime and minDistance have to be met for location update, but I need to get update every 3 seconds or 10 meters.

I tried to put 2 requests like this:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 3000, 0, this);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 10, this);
```

but it doesn't work, I only get update every 10 meters with this code, not every 3 seconds.

I'm working with API19 if that matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Documentation on requestLocationUpdate() says :

> requestLocationUpdates(String provider, long minTime, float
> minDistance, LocationListener listener)
>
> Register for location updates using the named provider, and a pending intent.

So you should be calling it like `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 3000, 10, this);`

But If you set minTime to 0, it will be called once when it first receives a location update, then it won't be called until you change your position in minDistance meters.

[Documentation Link for Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html)

**EDIT**

As per the Discussion with @Matej *I need to get update every 10 meters even if it happened in less than 3 seconds, and update every 3 seconds even if the location didn't change by more than 10 meters*

If you want to regularly `requestLocationUpdates`, you should use `Timer` and `TimerTask` and have `requestLocationUpdates` run once every 3 seconds

> schedule(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)
>
> Schedules the specified task for repeated fixed-delay execution,
> beginning after the specified delay.

Comment: But how can I make it call every 3 seconds or 10 meters? There has to be a way

Comment: But this sends me an update of location only if the location has changed by 10 meters AND 3 seconds has passed. I need to get update every 10 meters even if it happened in less than 3 seconds, and update every 3 seconds even if the location didn't change by more than 10 meters.

Comment: By setting it to 3000 ms it doesn't necessarily mean that you will get the location every 3rd second. The time is more or less a best case scenario.Anyways 10 meter distance will be more than enough for accurate data or Take TimerTask and request every three second

Comment: The problem is that this is part of assignment and we have to log the location every 3 seconds or 10 meters.

Comment: I've been thinking about that for a long time now, but I though I could make it work with requestLocationUpdates somehow. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I read this discussion for a similar problem.
I had to update location every second, but setting:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this);
```

I didn't achieve my goal.
In the official documentation I read that also if you fix a timerate for updates, it could be not keeped so rigid as setted. (I can't find anymore the developper page which talk about).

To have a fixed and sure timerate for updates I found this post.

My problem was that Location updates went to update (by observers) the activity and I got error using Timer (as suggested).
the error was:

```
Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

For anyone has similar problem I suggest to use Handler:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            notifyLocationObservers();
        }
    }, 1000);
```