# shop car location in map live like UBER

Tags: android

i would like to implement map like uber or grap car where there will be drivers and users, in the driver app i want to get the current location of the driver and put a live marker in the map that move when the driver move, from the user side when open the app he can see all the driver who is live, i cant find clear tutorial and how to do that, as i ready i understand that i may use onLocationChanged is that mean i keep send the driver location to database then in the user app i call these location and add marker to the map with these location i don't believe this is the right way to do it

```
class LocationUpdateListener implements LocationListener{

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // update your marker here
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47054752/locationmanager-requestlocationupdates-mintime-or-mindistance/47054953#47054953)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok after doing some research i found out it was easy to do , anyway am posting the ans in case someone need it

1 : in provider side when ever the location change we send it to real time database

```
googleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {



                    latitudeLocation = location.getLatitude();
                    longitudeLocation = location.getLongitude();

                    LatLng p1 = new LatLng(latitudeLocation, longitudeLocation);

                    mMap.clear();

                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(p1, 16));
                    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                    myRef = database.getReference("Location");
                    myRef.setValue(latitudeLocation+","+longitudeLocation);


    }

        });
```

2 : in the user side to see it in the map

```
 @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } else {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            } else {
            }
        }

 mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(false);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setIndoorLevelPickerEnabled(false);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);



        LatLng p1 = new LatLng(latitudeLocation, longitudeLocation);

        mylocation =  mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(p1).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.track_order_d)));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(p1, 16)); // 16 for the Zoom

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = database.getReference("Location");

        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                String [] separated = value.split(",");
                String latPos = separated[0].trim();
                String longiPos = separated[1].trim();

                Double dlat = Double.parseDouble(latPos);
                Double dlong = Double.parseDouble(longiPos);
                drivers = new LatLng(dlat,dlong);
                mMap.clear();
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(drivers).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.collection_d)));

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });










                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

with all thanks to everyone who try to help

Answer (score 2):

you can use `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);`  for request location updates and in `onLocationChanged(Location location)` you can show driver location on map. make sure you are clear map before put a pin (i.e. `map.clear()`)

Comment: @LimCho : please refer this link : [https://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/] for location manager and minor modification required

Answer (score 1):

As you think will be poor way, it can be faster. You can implement `XMPP Service` to continuously send live location. B'cos it seems faster way to achieve and require less effort.

You can send push(with lat-long) `onLocationChanged()` and the other side service will automatically detect that sent push from diver.

[This way](https://github.com/axcl/SMACK-API-Android-Demo) you can implement XMPP Service in app.

Comment: i found out that i can use firebase real time database to send the data to it and get it back from it also , but still i cant find clear tutorial

Comment: have you tried this : https://www.androidhive.info/2016/10/android-working-with-firebase-realtime-database/